Is there a way how to know that websocket subprotocols are rejected?
While connecting to a websocket server i set a subprotocol value.
this.websocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(connUrl, [subprotocol]);

It's up to server to check whether the subprotocol is allowed and valid. But if it isn't valid, how can the server provide this info to client? I control the server and this is the check on server-side:
server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
        if (request.headers["sec-websocket-protocol"] !== validProtocol) {
                socket.end(
                        "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" +
                                "Connection: close\r\n" +
                                "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
                                "Content-Length: 25\r\n" +
                                "\r\n" +
                                "Subprotocol not supported"
                );
                socket.destroy();
                return;
        }

        this.wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, ws => {
                this.wss.emit("connection", ws, request);
        });
});

Connecting work correctly, if protocol is correct, connection is made, otherwise, client has an error and no connection.
The issue is that on the client, I don't have access to the headers or response from the socket.end() call. So how otherwise can the server let the client know, that protocols are wrong?

Is this the library you are dealing with? If so, you will typically add a "close" event listener.

Yes, that is the library, but the close event can occur for various reasons. I want to know when the reason is the subprotocol.

"on the client, I don't have access to the headers or response" - why would you need them? The connection is closed with an error, that's all the client would care about.

What client are you using? A browser's new WebSocket in JavaScript?

I want to know reason, why is connection closed, whether it's because server rejected it or maybe just because no internet connection.

I don't think the details are available to the web client, probably for security reasons (notice there is no same-origin policy or some such for web sockets). All you'll get is an error event. Maybe it has different messages, but really for debugging connections failures you'll need developer tools that might provide insights.
